# Windows Phone 8 SDK Voice Commands and Fast App Resume

Tags: windows-phone-8, text-to-speech

I'm having a problem integrating Fast App Resume into my Windows Phone 8 app. When I hold the start button and enter a voice command, the command won't fire a Navigate event if the app is already loaded. I've tried intercepting every event I can when the app loads.... nothing.

Does anyone have any insight on how this should be handled in code?

Thanks!

Comment: They are talking about this over on the MS forums, too.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/68ab7745-15d4-4284-8a6f-9f10b94630fc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed with Microsoft that this behavior is indeed the case, and it is the way they intended it. They have left feedback to Engineering to take a look, but we can help it along by voting for it on UserVoice [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/3506293-fix-voicecommands-so-they-work-whether-the-app-is-).